# Vertex cover number of the line graph $L(K_n)$

Tags: graph-theory

For any graph $G=(V,E)$ let $\tau(G)$ be the minimum cardinality of a [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of $G$. Let $L(G)$ denote the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of $G$.

Given any positive integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$, what is the value of $\tau(L(K_n))$ where $K_n$ denotes the complete graph on $n$ points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vertex cover of $L(K_n)$ is just a subset of $E(K_n)$ whose complement is a matching. Since a maximum matching in $K_n$ has $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rceil$ edges,
$$\tau(L(K_n))=\binom n2-\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rceil=\left\lceil\frac{n^2}2\right\rceil-n.$$